# A question about independent random variable and probability distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose that $X_1,...,X_n$ are Random Variables and given that there exist an $k$ where k is an integer and $1\le k\le n-1$ s.t. the joint distribution $F_{X_1,...,X_k}$ are independent to $F_{X_k+1,...,X_n}$, prove that for all $1\le r \le k\le m\le n-1$ the joint distribution of $X_1,...,X_r$ is independent to joint distibutions $X_{m+1},...,X_n$

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i tried to use contradiction, but not sure how to get the contrary

Comment: I fail to see how a proof by contradiction would help. More to the point: what is the conclusion you try to reach, that is, what are you trying to prove?

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the fact that if $X$ and $Y$ are independent random variables, and if $f$ and $g$ are two (measurable ...) functions, then also $f(X)$ is independent from $g(Y)$.

Comment: but here is about the the joint pmf not pmf of a random variable

Comment: kjetil: +1. $ $